# Java compiler not able to infer type on generic chain

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, generic-programming

As mentioned below (to remark it as I might have explained myself badly):

> **I want to understand the principle behind this issue so that I can apply that knowledge to the real problem.**

**ISSUE START**

I am working in a system intended to be an abstract library to be used by many subsystems. The idea is to have an standard behaviour extensible by implementations.
My problem is that java compiler is not able to inferr method parameter type, even though it makes no sense since the boundaries are well set on every related generic class/method.

Below there is an example, the minimum example to reproduce the problem. I am aware it looks a bit silly in this example, but that is because of the simplification:

```
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gen<? extends Base> gen = new HijaGen();
        gen.applyTo(Hija.EXAMPLE);
    }
    private interface Base {
        String getName();
    }
    private enum Hija implements Base {
        EXAMPLE;
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return this.name();
        }
    }
    private interface Gen<T extends Base> {
        boolean applyTo(T base);
    }
    private static class HijaGen implements Gen<Hija> {
        @Override
        public boolean applyTo(Hija base) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically it says that applyTo expects a subclass of Base and Hija is not valid, which from my perspective makes no sense.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

This code is for a library, so that the solution could not be specifying the type since then it could not be extensible through particular implementations.

I am already aware that if I specify the generic type instead of throwing a type wildcard it will perfectly work. But my question is how is it possible that even though Hija subclasses Base, and method firm requires a subclass of Base it will never compile...

I want to understand the principle behind this issue so that I can apply that knowledge to the real problem.

Comment: The statement "this code is for a library" does not really help. It is important to know how the library is supposed to be accessed. The `main` method you provide is a sample call, but not one you'd expect to need a library for. What variable types will a client be concerning himself with when using the lib is the relevant question.

Comment: @daniu I think you are focused on something not important. The specific question is:
How is it possible that this method is not accepting Hija eventhough Hija satisfies (at least theoretically) what the method firm requires?

The mention about the library was just intended as a clarification about why I can not just use Gen<Hija> which is the fast solution

Comment: Well the answer you marked as accepted contains exactly what I was going for with my comment, namely that the call into the library will probably need to be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the lines of what Carlos has mentioned, there is one more way to resolve this. It can be used if you are sure of the suppliers of the implementation of `Gen<T>`.

Here, instead of the helper to call `applyTo()`, we define a factory method to create the instance of the `Gen` implementation and cast it to `Gen<Base>`, which in my opinion is safe for all practical purposes. Note that the factory method `get()` need not be static. The rest of the code remains unchanged from your sample.

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
    Gen<Base> gen = (Gen<Base>) get();
    gen.applyTo( Hija.EXAMPLE );
}

static Gen<? extends Base> get(){
    /* Create the instance of the Gen interface implementation here. */
    return new HijaGen();
}
```

### Explanation

`Gen<? extends Base>` expects to refer to an instance of an implementation of `Gen` that uses a type that is either `Base` or an sub-type of it. **Since a "sub-type" can be from one of many possible hierarchies** from `Base` downward (as shown in the picture below), it cannot be sure that the parameter passed to `applyTo()` method is of the same child hierarchy path and not just a 'relative' with the same ancestral parent `Base`. That is why it won't allow a call to `applyTo()` with its reference being of `Gen<? extends Base>` for a parameter of with reference as `Base`.

However, when the reference is `Gen<Base>`, it knows that `applyTo()` will accept any parameter that is a child type of `Base`. And hence, it stops worrying about type mismatch.

I have tried to show what I mean by different child hierarchy paths. It is like the case of a family tree.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A `Gen<? extends Base>` is a `Gen` of *something* which extends `Base`. It applies to *some* specific type of `Base` but we do not know which. In practice, this means you will never be able to call `applyTo` on a variable with type `Gen<? extends Base>`, except by passing null.

Change your code to

```
Gen<Hija> gen = new HijaGen();
gen.applyTo(Hija.EXAMPLE);
```

I suspect you'll probably say you can't do that, because your code is just an example, and the above is not possible in the real code. In which case you will need to give a better example

Comment: Or `Gen<? super Hija>`.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline or just `HijaGen`

Comment: I think there is a general principle the OP is after rather than just getting some random code to compile.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline See first paragraph

Comment: Hi 
Thanks to all, I will try to clarify a bit more:

This code is for a library, so that the solution could not be specifying the type since then it could not be extensible through particular implementations.

I am already aware that if I specify the generic type instead of throwing a type wildcard it will perfectly work. But my question is how is it possible that even though Hija subclasses Base, and method firm requires a subclass of Base it will never compile... 

I want to understand the principle behind this issue so that I can apply that knowledge to the real problem.

Comment: @DiegoFarras See first paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a similar problem explained in the docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html) and the problem that they propose is to make a helper (or wrapper) to clarify the types. So I guess you can try adding this function:

```
private static <T extends Base> boolean applyTo(Gen<T> gen, T base){
    return gen.applyTo(base);
}
```

And change the main function as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean b = applyTo(new HijaGen(), Hija.EXAMPLE);
}
```