# Why compare method of Comparator created with wildcard can't accept object?

Tags: java, comparator

In Java it is legal to create a comparator object like this:

```
Comparator<? super Number> comparator = new Comparator<Object>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        // implementation here
    }
};
```

But you can't use this object for a simple call like this:

```
Object o1 = new Object(), o2 = new Object();
comparator.compare(o1, o2);
```

Why so? I thought `? super Number` means Number and all its superclasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose instead you had used `? super Double`:

```
Comparator<? super Double> comparator = new Comparator<Object>() {
    // ...
};
```

What you are telling the compiler is that you have a Comparator which

- *might be* a `Comparator<Double>`, or
- *might be* a `Comparator<Number>`, or
- *might be* a `Comparator<Object>`, or
- *might be* a `Comparator<Serializable>`.

Even though you initialized it with a `Comparator<Object>`, the compiler doesn’t know that, because the compiler doesn’t execute code.  The compiler only knows that the variable holds a Comparator of one of the above types.

Since the variable *might* hold a comparator of a type more specific than Object, the compiler will not assume that it’s okay to pass Object.

Answer (score 1):

`Comparator<? super Number> comparator` means that `comparator` refers to something known to be able to accept a `Number` (or it's `null`).

A `Comparator<Object>` *can* accept a `Number`; but the compiler doesn't know if the value referred to by a `Comparator<? super Number>` is a `Comparator<Object>`, or a `Comparator<Number>` any more. All it knows is that it's something that can accept a `Number`, so that's all it will allow you to pass.

> Why so? I thought `? super Number` means Number and all its superclasses.

No: it means that `Number` is an acceptable type to pass as a parameter. To put that another way, `Number` is a subtype of the acceptable parameter type. To put that another way, the acceptable parameter type is a supertype of `Number`, so it's fine to pass a `Number`.

See: [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Comment: I still don't get it. If the acceptable parameter type is a supertype of Number and it is fine to pass a Number, why it is not fine to pass an Object, which is a supertype of Number?

Comment: @saidfagan because it could be a `Comparator<Number>` instead: that's also a `Comparator<? super Number>`. If you pass an `Object` to that, it will fail.

Comment: Now, I got it, thank you. How about `Comparator<? extends Number>`? By this logic, does that mean you can't send anything as parameter to `compare` method?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `o1` and `o2` cannot be used as parameters is because they are "more general" than `Number` and hence they **may** point to an instance of a class that is part of a different hierarchy starting at some point in parent chain of `Number`. Something like, `Son` class is directly in the hierarchical line of `Father`, but not in the hierarchy of `Grandfather` class's `SecondSon`. So, a reference to an instance of `Grandfather` class cannot be passed since it could be pointing to an instance in its `SecondSon`'s hierarchy.

I have tried to explain a similar point [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59720175/2747642).